# SSIS missing connection types

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have just installed visual studio 2022 and I'm trying to set up a connection to import an excel file. When I click to create a new Excel connection I get the error

```
The connection manager 'EXCEL' is not properly installed on this computer. (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design)

For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com:80/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%C2%AE%20Visual%20Studio%C2%AE&ProdVer=17.8.34316.72&EvtSrc=Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.SR&EvtID=ConnectionManagerNotInstalled&LinkId=20476
```

The link there doesn't work. I tried googling this and only found people back in 2014 having the same issue, they resolved it by installing a service pack. I checked for and installed updates to visual studio but no improvement.

When I click on connection managers this is the list that I get which doesn't have Excel or Flatfile in there, and probably a few others missing.

I don't know how to add them.

[image]

Comment: Just a comment but I had a similar experience with SSMS, the latest version didn't have the Excel Import facility...  It had been moved into Azure, so I stuck with the older version of SSMS.  It might be the same with VS....  Good luck :-)

Comment: Same problem with fresh install and VS 20222, have you find a solution ? Thank

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't yet been able to resolve it.